# Import Data From Web Page Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to import player snap counts from a website but my code produces an error at the get elements by tag name ("tr") and I do not know why.  I have used the code to import web data from another site and I do not understand why it errors.  The URL I am trying to access is: https://www.footballoutsiders.com/stats/nfl/snap-counts?year=2020&team=ALL&week=1&position=ALL

The code stops working at the 'For Each tr' statement.

Suggestions, thoughts, answers?

```
    Set hTable = html.querySelector("new-table modal-second-col responsive-enabled")

    Dim td As Object, tr As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    
    r = 1
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        For Each tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            r = r + 1: c = 1
            If r > 3 Then
                For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                    .Cells(r - 2, c) = IIf(c = 2, "'" & td.innerText, td.innerText)
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the debugger and inspect the hTable element. Make sure it has tr elements. Use the immediate window to test some code ( print the element to the debug console )

Comment: This is what I see when inspecting the site's element

Comment: Sorry, forgot to finish the comment.  When I hover the Set hTable = statement it says 'Nothing' so I assume that my table is empty. Any thoughts on the Set statement?  As I said, it has worked in the past.

Comment: 1) That page appears to be very dynamic and so content may be loaded from a different endpoint 2) At a quick glance, your css selector list appears to be wrong a) because doesn't match anything on the page b) from experience, based on naming in your selector, I suspect your syntax is wrong e.g.  class selector needs to have a "." preceding the class name

Comment: you also need to login to the site to access the data

Comment: Yes, it does.  I manually login at this point; I will try and add login script once I get this part figured out.  It has been quite challenging.  I have redone the script and now I am able to get the first column of the table that I am trying to import the data from. Any clues on how to get the complete table?  QHarr, I tried to read up on css info, good stuff and I tried to change things up and failed. New code to follow

Comment: 'Sub Get_Web_Data3()
Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim website As String
Dim tblSNP As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim headers()
headers = Array("Player", "Team", "Position", "Total Snaps", "Offense Snaps", "Offense Snap Rate", "Defense Snaps", "Defense Snap Rate", "Special Team Snaps", "Special Team Snap Rate")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

' Website to go to.
website = "https://www.footballoutsiders.com/stats/nfl/snap-counts?year=2020&team=ALL&week=1&position=ALL"'

Comment: '' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
request.Open "GET", website, False

' Send the request for the webpage.
request.send

' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
html.body.innerHTML = response'

Comment: '' Get snap counts from the specified element on the page.
tblSNP = html.getElementsByClassName("new-table modal-second-col responsive-enabled")(0).innerText

Debug.Print tblSNP
'write headers to ws 
r = 1
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        
    End With

End Sub'